# How to check if an observable is empty in RXSwift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, observable, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

i have initialized an empty observable like this:

```swift
var subCategories = Observable<[String]>.empty()
```

How can i check if the observable is empty or not? I would like to show a "empty view" to the user if the observable is empty else show the data in tableview.

Comment: Empty Observable refers to an Observable emit a single `onComplete`. The use-case you described should be implemented with an Observable which emits `[String]` with length from 0 to n.

Answer (score 1):

create a bool Observable to show/hide your emptyView:

```
let hideEmptyView = subCategories.map{!$0.isEmpty}
```

then bind this `hideEmptyView` Bool Observable to `yourEmptyView.rx.isHidden`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filter on the Observable :

```
viewModel.filteredUsers.asObservable()
        .filter({ [weak self] array in
            guard let self = self else {return true}
            
            if array.isEmpty {
                self.emptyListContainer.alpha = 1
                self.tableView.alpha = 0
            } else {
                self.emptyListContainer.alpha = 0
                self.tableView.alpha = 1
                
            }
            return true
        })
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell", cellType: ContactsTableViewCell.self)) { (row, user, cell) in
        cell.titleLbl.text = user.name
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

one line solution is to have something like this

`yourBehaviourRelay.map{$0.isEmpty}.bind(to: yourView.rx.isHidden).disposed(by: DisposeBag())`

Answer (score -1):

use a **BehaviourRelay** other than **Observable**.

```
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

var subCategories = BehaviorRelay<[String]>(value: [])
let emptyView = UIStackView()

func addObservers() {
    subCategories.asObservable().subscribe { _ in
        self.emptyView.isHidden = !self.subCategories.value.isEmpty
    }.disposed(by: DisposeBag())
}
```